# Conditional string substitution in awk

Tags: awk

Hoping to find an awk one-liner for conditional substitution.

To substitute `addr` with `addr-set` whenever the fifth row of a line contains an expression, that equals the expression in the third row of any other line.

Source/input format is:

```
set addr-set GRP-Africa addr NET-10.1.1.0-24
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr GRP-Africa
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr GRP-Europe
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr GRP-Middle-East
set addr-set GRP-Europe addr NET-10.1.2.0-24
set addr-set GRP-Europe addr GRP-Germany
set addr-set GRP-Germany addr NET-10.1.3.0-24
set addr-set GRP-Middle-East addr NET-10.1.4.0-24
```

Desired output format would be:

```
set addr-set GRP-Africa addr NET-10.1.1.0-24
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr-set GRP-Africa
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr-set GRP-Europe
set addr-set GRP-EMEA addr-set GRP-Middle-East
set addr-set GRP-Europe addr NET-10.1.2.0-24
set addr-set GRP-Europe addr-set GRP-Germany
set addr-set GRP-Germany addr NET-10.1.3.0-24
set addr-set GRP-Middle-East addr NET-10.1.4.0-24
```

Nested Groups need `addr-set`, but in sourcefile everything is `addr`.
This looks like a job for awk with sub, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: please add code you've tried to question as well.. if you check https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info, there's a link http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ which has examples of two file processing with awk... you'd need that here on same input file - first pass to build array of 3rd columns.. and second pass to act upon 4th/5th columns based on the array that was built in first pass..

Comment: hek2mgl's solution works like a charm:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to process the file twice for that. In the first run, you'll store the 3rd columns of each row in an array, in the second run you'll check if $5 is stored in that array:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3];next} $5 in a {$4="addr-set"}1' file file
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! <3